# Auto deployment using capistrano without keeping old releases

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

It's the first time I'm trying to make automatic deployment. Currently when I deploy to a server capistrano keeps all releases and symlinkc `current` folder to the newest one. So I actually get a path for my app `/var/www/my_app/current` and I have all other releases in `/var/www/my_app/releases` I'm wondering if there is a way to have only a single release so I wouldn't have directories like `current` and `releases` and my app would just sit in `/var/www/my_app/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. It is probably possible to hack together, but the effort involved would make me encourage you to look at another tool if you don't prefer the way Cap is doing this.

With that said, you can approximate this in a couple of ways:

You can set `keep_releases` to 1, which will make sure that all prior releases in the releases folder are deleted after successful deployment. This is helpful if you have very limited space, but you lose the ability to roll back, which is a signature feature of Capistrano.

Also, you can deploy to another location, let's say `/var/www/deployments/myapp`, and then symlink `/var/www/myapp` to `/var/www/deployments/myapp/current`. Make sure that this is a soft link (`ln -s`).

Finally, you could do the last option but create a post deployment task to rsync changes rather than symlink.